# How to delete uploaded files after session expires ? PHP

Tags: php

I want to delete uploaded images from a directory when the user exit the browser or when he log out.

Comment: Are you able to identify a user whose session expired?

Comment: no I don't know how !

Comment: You must have some script going on when a user logs out. Why not deleting the wanted file at that time?

Comment: if I set a timer for php session how can I delete files after session expiry ?

Comment: @GeekSimo - Just write a script to tidy up once in a while. Simple, fault tolerant and easy to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with jQuery and PHP

```
window.onunload = function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "removefile.php"
    })
}
```

But it's better to use CronJob and PHP for auto cleaning.

Comment: this has a couple of problems. Browser/computer/network crashes. Person not using JS.

Comment: Yes, sometimes doesn't work, it's better to use cronjob and php to detect unwanted files and remove them.

Comment: How to delete files using cron job and php ?

Comment: Look up `find` i.e. `find /path/here -atime 1 -exec rm -f {}` (need to check as that is off the top of my head and should wipe stuff over a day old that has not been used

Answer (score 1):

Why not have a caretaker task that just runs periodically and tidies things up?

E.g. A file in an uploaded directory that has been there for X hours can be deleted.

No need to identify if a session has exited. Sometimes it might exited in abnormal circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using the following code

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    $.ajax({
       url: "deleteimage.php"
    });
};
```